# how can I convert a fraction inputted as string to float in C

Tags: c

A string is input as a fraction, how can I convert this string to float?

In the below code it always show the first number only without any calculations i.e : 2.00

```
int main (void)
{
    string fraction = "2/4";
    float sum = atof(fraction);
    printf("sum : %.2f\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to split the string into a nominator and denominator string and then apply `atof` to each individually.

Comment: How is this code even compiling in C? There is no `string` data type in C. Also, `atof` expects `const char*`  as input..

Comment: This duplicate has all the tools you'll need to do this. It's by no means a beginner's topic though. K & R has a good chapter on expression parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this directly. With atof you e.g. change "2.034" to 2.034 (f), but not an expression (with a division in your case).

Instead, if you know there will be always a divider symbol, search for the divider symbol, than extract the left and right part, use atoi (string to integer), and divide the two integers (after casting to float).

Comment: the string will always be in  the format "1/4" , i was able to extract the left and right part but am not able to convert them to integer , always gives me error message .

Comment: What error message?

Comment: int main ()
{
  char str[] ="1/4";
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok (str,"/");
  int intpch[2];
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
      intpch[i] = atoi(pch);
      pch = strtok (NULL, "/");
    }

  }
  float result = intpch[0]/intpch[1];
  printf("Result %i / %i is : %.2f\n ",intpch[0],intpch[1],result);

  return 0;
}  // the result is 0.00

Comment: it has worked finally

Comment: int main ()
{
  char str[] ="1/4";
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok (str,"/");
  float floatpch[2];
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
      floatpch[i] = atof(pch);
      pch = strtok (NULL, "/");
    }

  }
  float result = floatpch[0]/floatpch[1];
  printf("Result %.2f / %.2f is : %.2f\n ",floatpch[0],floatpch[1],result);

  return 0;
}

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your assumption is wrong.

A *string* like `"2/4"`, **is** `"2/4"`, it's not `"0.5"`, i.e., it does not evaluate itself to produce the result of the expected expression.

That said, `atof()` family is not safe (at least, poor with reporting / handling error conditions, which, in your particular case, would have been very useful, should you have checked the return code), please use `strtod()` and family.